# Debug JS Remotely is not showing on iOS simulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I don't know why "Debug JS Remotely" is not showing on iOS simulator

[image]

Versions:

・RN：v0.62.0

・OS:：macOS 10.15.3

・Xcode：11.3.1

Any solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With new react native versions, They have disabled hot reloading and live reloading with fast refresh and for your case Debug JS remotely has been changed to Start Debug. That will open up a browser in your system.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts.

Comment: It seems like "Start debug" opens flipper but doesn't allow remote debugging. Did they also removed support for remote JS execution?

Answer (score 0):

You're already debugging as you've turned on debug JS remotely(Start Debug newer version) ,open chrome and open inspect and tap on console ,you'll get the logs there, else to stop Just press on stop debugging to find debug JS remotely